# How to use behaviour of p:multiSelectListbox in p:selectOneMenu in primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

i want to use effect of multiseleclist box shown at http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/multiSelectListbox.xhtml .
In Select one menu like http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/oneMenu.xhtml

Is there any way to do this.

I need to display list in drop down , when user select option 1 it come with option1.1 and when user select option1.1 it come with option1.1.1.
Thanks
[image]

See in image

Comment: Why can't you use the MultiSelectListbox in your case?

Comment: @GregD, if the first level element is more it take more area on browser, so that the UI will take more space.